# Publishing apps on playstore with flutter

Tags: android, flutter

Can we publish apps with default flutter icon on playstore? Is it mandatory to change the icon before publishing?

Comment: Hi , Its mandatory to change icons as well as . You have to upload some other pics in different sizes....

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's allowed due to Google's [Impersonation and Intellectual Property policy](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/topic/9876963) but you can easily  change the default app icon to your icon or any other icon using the [flutter_launcher_icons](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons) library.